# String is simultaneously greater than zero and empty

Tags: bash, comparison

Would someone please care to explain how on earth this is supposed to make sense:

Contents of `insanity.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG=""

if [ -n $ARG ]; then
    echo string is greater than zero
fi

if [ -z $ARG ]; then
    echo string is empty
fi
```

Running the script:

```
[USERNAME@login001 clusterUtils]$ ./insanity.sh
string is greater than zero
string is empty
```

Currently using [this](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php#test) tutorial at the moment.

Comment: From `help test`: `-n STRING`: True if string is not empty.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: That tutorial seems to very... pragmatic. [Here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) is a tutorial that focuses more on correctness and accuracy without simplifying away important aspects.

Comment: @thatotherguy I agree the tutorial from ryanstutorials.net isn't very good. Example bad practices: `[ $2 == 'yes' ]` will probably get errors if `$2` isn't exactly one word long (and have no wildcards), and in shells that don't allow `==` as a synonym for `=` (if you're not worried about portability, use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`). Similarly, `[ -r $1 ]` will evaluate to true if `$1` is empty (or equal to "= -r", or ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is happening because you're not quoting `$ARG` inside `[ ... ]`.

Without quoting your code is *effectively* running as:

```
if [ -n ]; then
    echo string is greater than zero
fi

if [ -z ]; then
    echo string is empty
fi
```

**Any non-empty string between `[ ... ]` will evaluate to true**, hence both `if` conditions are successful.

---

**Fix:** It is recommended to use `[[ ... ]]` as you're using `bash`:

```
arg=""

if [[ -n $arg ]]; then
    echo 'string is greater than zero'
fi

if [[ -z $arg ]]; then
    echo 'string is equal to zero, empty'
fi
```

`[[ ... ]]` doesn't require your variables to be quoted like `[ ... ]` sine `[` is an external command and `[[ ... ]]` is a builtin bash construct.

Also avoid all uppercase variables in your script to avoid conflicts with reserved env variables.

Comment: It's also entirely reasonable to double-quote the variables (in either `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`). I tend to recommend double-quoting *all* variable references unless there's a specific reason not to, just because it's too hard to keep track of where it's safe to leave the double-quotes off and where it's dangerous.